# ERROR: column "bob" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tag WHERE field1=Bob

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to make a query in postgresql on a remote DB through terminal with Node.js.

The below two queries return succesfully:

```
psql -h *** -p *** -U *** -d *** -c 'SELECT * FROM tag'
```

.

```
psql -h *** -p *** -U *** -d *** -c 'SELECT * FROM tag WHERE id=1'
```

However, with string queries as such:

```
psql -h *** -p *** -U *** -d *** -c 'SELECT * FROM tag WHERE field1=Bob'
```

gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "bob" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tag WHERE field1=Bob
```

This is my tag table:

```
  id  | _account_id | tag_type | jsondata | field1
```

Could you please tell me what would be the issue in my queries?

Comment: Does your table have the columns field1 and Bob? Field1 is a poor _column_ name. Bob is probably a value, so it should be within single quotes.

Comment: You need to quote your string.

Comment: @HoneyBadger `'SELECT * FROM tag WHERE field1="Bob"'` this also gives the same issue with quotes: `column "Bob" does not exist.`

Comment: @jarlh Yes it does.

Comment: In sql, strings are quoted with single quotes, double quotes are used for identifiers.

Comment: Simple quote : field1='Bob'

Comment: Single quotes, like `'Bob'`. However, they need to be escaped here.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks! That solved my issue <3

Comment: Try with single quotes around Bob (ie 'Bob')

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: `psql -c ...` isn't really intended for interactive usage. Just start `psql`, **then** enter the queries you want to run

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly, it was about quotes. Thanks to jarlh (whose solution is on comments), I needed to use single quotes instead of double quotes. This worked:

```
"SELECT * FROM tag WHERE field1='Bob'"
```